# Avoid having to make a bunch of different popups for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Problem

I have my information in an array, I'm able to grab that data dynamically from `var MLA` and display it in a tooltip / popup window (see `index.html`) above a photo for each of MLA's/ people on the page, however there are 56 different people on different locations on the page, which won't be neatly presented in a grid.

## Question

**a)** Is there any way to avoid having to make 56 different tooltips, so that I could click on an image of a person (see `index.html`) and the tooltip would appear relative to person's image with the dynamic content inside.

### scripts.js

```
    $(function() {

        // MLAs
        var MLAs = [
          {
            "Name": "Nancy Allan",
            "Age": 62,
            "Constuency": "St. Vital",
            "Party": "NDP",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "Ethnicity": "White"
          },
          {
            "Name": "James Allum",
            "Age": null,
            "Constuency": "Fort Garry-Riverview",
            "Party": "NDP",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Ethnicity": "White"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Rob Altemeyer",
            "Age": null,
            "Constuency": "Wolseley",
            "Party": "NDP",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Ethnicity": "White"
          }]

        // Shows a popup with MLA information
        $(".headshot").click(function(){
            var idx = $(this).index() - 1;

            $(".tooltip").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".tooltipName").html(MLAs[idx].Name);
            $(".tooltipParty").html(MLAs[idx].Party);
            $(".tooltipConstuency").html(MLAs[idx].Constuency);
            $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(MLAs[idx].Ethnicity) + ",";
            $(".tooltipAge").html(MLAs[idx].Age);
        });

    // Positioning of the tooltips
    $('.headshot').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);

        img.click(function(){
            $('.tooltip')
            .show(100)
            .text(img.attr('alt'))
            .offset({
                top : img.offset().top + img.height(),
                left : img.offset().left
            });
        });
    });
 });
```

### index.html

```
            <div class="tooltip">
                <div class="info">
                    <p class="tooltipName"></p>
                    <p class="tooltipParty"></p> <p class="tooltipConstuency"></p>
                    <p class="tooltipEthnicity"></p> <p class="tooltipAge"></p>
                    </div><!-- /.info -->

                    <div class="arrow-down">
                    </div><!-- /.arrow-down -->
                </div><!-- /.tooltip -->

<img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" alt="" id="0" class="headshot NDP Female White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" alt="" id="1" class="headshot NDP Male White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/altemeyer.jpg" alt="" id="2" class="headshot NDP Male White">
```

### tooltip.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
TOOLTIP
----------------------------------*/

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -12px;
    top: -5px;
}

.info {
    @include serifLight;
    background: $yellow;
    color: $black;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 9%;
    text-align: center;

    p {
        margin: 0px;
    }
}

.tooltipName, {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.tooltipEthnicity, .tooltipAge {
    display: inline;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid $yellow;
    position: relative;
    left: 36px;
}
```

Comment: _"and the tooltip would appear relative to person's image with the dynamic content inside."_ Describing `css` property `position` value `relative` ? , or , `MLAs` data "relative" to `img` attribute data ?

Comment: Here is an example (_tested only in latest Chrome, Firefox, & Safari_): http://jsbin.com/taqefutevu/1/edit?output

Comment: @istos Can you explain what's going on in your example a little more step by step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.offset()` values to work for the positioning of the tooltip.

Try something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a4azvmo/)

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var img = $(this);

    img.click(function(){
             $('.tooltip')
             .show(100)
             .text(img.attr('alt'))
             .offset({
                top : img.offset().top + img.height(),
                left : img.offset().left
        });
    });



});
```

Comment: Been having some problems with your solutions, seems to work on your JSFiddle, I've updated my code in `scripts.js` in my original question